# Como enviar y recibir información en una misma función ajax-flask

Tags: javascript, html, python, flask, raspberry-pi

no soy un experto programador pero me encuentro en la siguiente situación:

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con una raspberry Pi, donde hago control de un sistema hidraulico por medio de python.

He creado ya un programa en html y javascript con la función ajax y un button, el cual tiene la siguiente sintaxis:

```
<input type = "number" style="width : 230px" name = "number" id = "number" placeholder = "Input the number of cycles" min="1" max="99" >
<button onclick = "sendData()" class='btn btn-primary'>START PROCESS</button>
<script>
    function sendData() {
        $.ajax({
            data : {
                number : $('#number').val()
            },
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{{ url_for('start') }}"
        });
    }
</script>
```

De esta manera logro enviar el numero de veces que se repetira un ciclo for en flask, el cual tiene la siguiente sintaxys:

```
@app.route('/start', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def start():
   n = request.form['number']
   for i in range(n):
      #proceso industrial dura alrededor de "10 segundos"
      data = [i+1,variable1,variable2]
      response = make_response(json.dumps(data))
      response.content_type = 'application/json'
      return response
```

Donde aqui lo que quiero es una vez presionado el boton en html START PROCESS envie el numero colocado en la casilla de texto number a mi codigo flask para que ejecute el ciclo for, pero cada que ejecute el ciclo for me regrese los datos capturados por los sensores (que puse en mi codigo como variable1 y variable2) guardados en el vector data, y estos sean regresados al programa html para que sean graficados en tiempo real despues de cada proceso.

Para las graficas me gustaria usar el ejemplo mostrado en el siguiente video de youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gopZN_yVANQ&t=91s

Entonces resumiendo quiero que una vez presionado el boton se empiece a ejecutar el codigo start de flask que recibe el numero escrito en la celda de texto, y cada vez que termine el ciclo for en el codigo start regrese los datos de los sensores y puedan ser graficados como en el video que les comparti (cabe mencionar que ya logre que funcione la ejecución de la función start, sin embargo no logro que grafique que es la principal petición de ayuda en esta pregunta).

Alguna ayuda que me puedan proporcionar para que pueda ejecutarse el codigo del grafico?obviamente asi como lo tengo sin el uso de formularios y sin tener que refrescar la pagina.

Espero haber sido claro con la pregunta y ojala puedan ayudarme ya sea con el codigo mostrado en el video o algun otro metodo de grafica en javascript

Por ultimo me gustaria mencionar que esto lo quiero hacer solo con el uso de flask, html y javascript.

Saludos y gracias por su tiempo